# Control Chat Volume of ping sound in any chatroom

Tags: script, chat

### Screenshot / Code Snippet

[image: chat sound slider]

### About

This script adds a sound volume control to each SE chatroom.

I created it after seeing complaints about the sound being too loud.

The script hooks-up into the volume control of the jPlayer used by Stack Exchange.

This post is a spin-off of my original MSE answer: [Audio slider for chat pings](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/227028/audio-slider-for-chat-pings/250835#250835)

#### License

CC0

#### Download

[Source Code](https://github.com/rschrieken/SmallButHandy/blob/master/chatvolume.user.js)

[Direct Install](https://github.com/rschrieken/SmallButHandy/raw/master/chatvolume.user.js)

#### Platform

The script is expected to work in any by Stack Exchange supported browser with a decent script manager installed, like TamperMonkey or ViolentMonkey.
Don't expect support for GreaseMonkey 4.

### Contact

Leave bugs or feature requests as answers on this question or submit direct PRs if you have immediate improvements to offer.

### Code

The code is JavaScript with heavy use of jQuery.